# Best way to predict area of effect of area-effect spells?

Tags: baldurs-gate, baldurs-gate-enhanced

In Baldur's Gate Enhanced, what's the best way to predict the area that will be affected by, say, Web?  Obviously I want to affect enemies and not friends.

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in option to show the Area of Effect radius of spells when you're targeting them. It's visually a bit odd looking, and it can't be enabled in-game, but it is there!

To enable it you need to open up the file `Baldur.lua` and edit it since the setting isn't in the menus like many others are.

Where is the file? (Replace "Name" below with your username)

- On Windows: `C:\Users\Name\Documents\Baldur's Gate - Enhanced Edition\Baldur.lua`
- On MacOS: `/Users/Name/Documents/Baldur's Gate - Enhanced Edition/Baldur.lua`
- On Linux: `~/.local/share/Baldur's Gate - Enhanced Edition/Baldur.lua`

What do I do to it?

1. Open the file with your favorite text editor (Notepad on Windows or TextEdit on MacOS is fine).
2. Find the line that says: `SetPrivateProfileString('Game Options','Show AOE','0')`
3. Change that line to: `SetPrivateProfileString('Game Options','Show AOE','1')`
4. Enjoy your new AoE indicators so you can stop roasting your own party with fireballs.

Answer (score 1):

Look here at [Baldurs Gate Wikia](http://baldursgate.wikia.com/wiki/Stinking_Cloud). Every spell has a *"Range"* and a *"Area of Effect"*. In Baldur's Gate you could use "X" key to see a X and Y coords (this perhaps can be helpful). But you are not able to marked the area affected by a spell. You have to learn how to use AoE spells by intuition (in this is also a "charm of BG").

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking with the coordinates, but I don't know how to map coordinate dimensions into feet yet.  I have measured the line of sight area as approximately 900 X-coords wide and 660 Y-coords high.  I'm not playing with a mage right now so I haven't gotten around to measuring a spell area of effect in coordinates.

Comment: Even though the spell is suppose to affect your party, I remember it doesn't... it's not consistent, but I remember fireballing things right in front of me when I found out it doesn't actually hurt my own members.  Or maybe I gained fire immunity... I don't remember.